# Navigation drawer activity

Tags: android, android-studio, android-navigation-drawer

Ребята, подскажите можно ли в меню заменить стандартные иконки на свои картинки из интернета и как это сделать? я просто скачал из инета картинку в папку drawable в activity_main_drawer в android:icon указал через @drawable свою картинку, наивно полагая, что всё проканает. А нет( Может вообще не в том направлении двигаюсь.

Answer (score 0):

Да, можно. Для начала обязательно к [прочтению](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer).

Внутри меню Navigation Drawer'а:

```
<item android:id="@+id/menuitem1"
 android:icon="@drawable/someimage"
 android:title="Описание"/>
```

Comment: А я так и делал, но она почему-то просто квадратом отображается. Ок, вопрос - как тогда подогнать размер обычной картинки под иконку

Comment: почитал, что фон должен быть прозрачным, то есть по факту просто картинку загрузить нельзя?